# How many serial ports can be configured in Windows 7?

Tags: networking, windows-7, port

I am trying to learn the maximum number of serial ports that can be configured on Windows 7.  Any information on this will be greatly appreciated.  I'm having trouble finding this.

Comment: How many do you really need?

Comment: We need to connect around 80 devices.

Comment: What kind of devices? Perhaps RS485 would be a better alternative.

Comment: Unfortunately I am locked in to RS-232 due to hardware limitations.  We are planning to proxy the serial port via Ethernet using third-party hardware.  We are in the planning stages and I couldn't find the maximum number of ports I could configure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows 6.0+ support **256** Communications Port devices.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  That's more than we'll need.  Where did you get this information?  I will need a reference in my documentation.

Comment: Honestly I don't know where or if MS has this documented. It's a definitely the current limit however.

Comment: Windows has supported 256 ports since Windows 95, at least according to the API documentation.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers I think that's only for 32-bit apps; IIRC 16-bit are limited to 9... Do you have a link to something official looking? I couldn't find anything.

Comment: You may be right. I don't have any references to hand but recall that I looked up the information when I was writing a comms program for Win95, which was obviously a few years ago.

Comment: Might be [useful](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/F7A9002D7B8E31E7862568D6006BD10B) .

Answer (score 1):

> The maximum number of COM and LPT ports that Windows NT supports is 256. This is a limitation in Control Panel and does not represent a limitation of the hardware platform. In both Intel x86 and MIPS machines, the number of COM and LPT ports is only limited by available interrupts, I/O addresses and, ultimately, 4,294,967,295 (32 bits).

This link from Microsoft.com explains it well:

[Maximum Number of LPT and COM Ports - Archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20150511100555/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/100111)

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.