# Exceeding the 256 serial COM PORT limit?

Tags: linux, windows, usb, serial, com-port

Can I use more than 256 COM PORTS on a single host?

From this answer, it looks like it's a software/OS limit only: [How many serial ports can be configured in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/496667/how-many-serial-ports-can-be-configured-in-windows-7)

I'm unable to figure out how to actually increase the limit so that Windows can see more than 256 devices. Is this possible for linux/debian?

Comment: **You cannot increase the limit.**  The limit is the same on all supported versions of Windows.

Comment: How about for linux? Can this limit be increased?